# React & Webpack & Docker: Inject env's at runtime in production to the docker-container

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, environment-variables

Hi try to deploy my React-App with Docker and Webpack. My problem is that I want to inject my Environment Variables at runtime.

If I run my docker I want that the env ENV_TEST has the value testValue

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e ENV_TEST=testValue client
```

Webpack-file:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env.ENV_TEST": JSON.stringify(
        process.env.ENV_TEST
    ),
}),
```

Docker-file:

```
ENV ENV_TEST=default
```

React:

```
console.log(process.env.ENV_TEST)
//-->default
```

At the moment my ENV_TEST has the value default (form the Docker-file form the build-time).
If I don't define the value in my Docker-File the ENV_TEST is undefined. If I run my docker container with `-e ENV_TEST=testValue` I want to overwrite the default value with the value testValue.

Thx for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for you answers. I ended up with this solution: https://github.com/kunokdev/cra-runtime-environment-variables

Answer (score 3):

You can't override this env variable at runtime since its runtime is the client browser (I'm guessing that it's a react app die to the tags).

Its value gets overriden at build time, and from there the value is hard coded in the js bundle.

You can pass a dynamic value to the html, and make your app to read it from there.

###Edit

```html
// index.html

<html>
...
  <body>
    <script>
       window.TEST_ENV = '<%= EJVaraibale %>';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx for you answer. What do you mean with " pass a dynamic value to the html"?

Comment: I meant that you can "pass" a server value, as a global variable on your `window` object, and your react app will use it if it is available.

Comment: Other option is to embed it as data-attibute on your root element, (I don't like it)

Answer (score 1):

When we did this for our React App, we wrote a small express server that takes the index.html and injects the config into it by replacing the string content that we put as a placeholder in index.html while building the app for production.